# How do I post code to GitHub?

Tags: github

I've looked everywhere but I can't find any way to post code to GitHub. I tried making a repository but then it tells me I have to download a command prompt thing?

Why can't I just post code directly to it? Is there any other way?

Comment: I feel you on not wanting to mess with a command prompt. I tried to go the GUI route with git, but ultimately found that the the command line is how I had to use it. Counter-intuitively, the GUI's didn't seem to work that well and it was much easier to use the command prompt for this situation.

Comment: For visual studio projects the command prompt isn't required (though I recommend installing for any needed flexibility from the standard gui deployment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are simply looking for a way to put some code online, then you can use another feature of that site calles "[gists](https://gist.github.com/)".

If you are on a mac, then there is [another app you can use (made by the GitHub guys)](http://mac.github.com/).

But the most relevant piece of software is what you refer to as " command prompt thing", which is a version control application with a relatively steep learning curve called [GIT](http://git-scm.com/).

On a final note you might be misunderstanding what GitHub is useful for and might be better off looking at something a bit less complicated. If you are willing to explain exactly what you are looking for then i'm sure the StackOverflow community will be willing to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use github's [gist](https://gist.github.com/).
Although, the main point of using github is to share [git](http://git-scm.com/) repositories.

Answer (score 2):

While GitHub has recently added limited support for editing files through the web interface, it's intended as hosting for software projects using the Git source control software. The most-used interface is the command-line `git` tool, though there are graphical interfaces such as TortoiseGit as well as Git components for many IDEs.

If all you're looking for is a place to put small code fragments for sending to others (like a pastebin), then you probably want Gists instead: http://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Github](http://github.com/) is a code hosting site for [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

The "command prompt thingy" is likely Git. If you don't use Git, it's unlikely you want Github either.

Luckily there are graphical Git front ends such as [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html).